# what is the Different categories of pointers?

Tags: c++, c

Can any body explains about the different categories  of pointer(like wild pointers)?

Comment: can you clarify? what categories? wild pointer is not a standard term.

Comment: Wild pointer is de facto standard term, meaning an uninitialized pointer variable pointing to some random location. For other similar terms, ask Google.

Comment: Never heard of a wild pointer, and I have been doing this for a while.

Comment: Me neither, but Wikipedia seems to like it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Valid** pointer: one pointing to a real object in memory
- **Invalid** pointer: one pointing to memory that is not what it is supposed to be.
- **NULL** pointer: A pointer whose value is 0 and thus points at nothing.
- **Dangling** pointer (also sometimes wild pointer): one pointing to memory that has been deleted/freed.
- **Smart** pointer: Not really a pointer at all, but rather an object which acts like a pointer, but manages the memory for you.

Comment: AFAIK NULL pointer's value needs not be zero (the bit pattern may vary between machines), though the NULL constant evaluates to zero.

Comment: I could classify "Dangling" and "Invalid" as the same thing.  Null too, really, but its verifiably invalid.

Comment: But logically they're different. A pointer is invalid if you've run out of bounds or mistakenly assigned it to the wrong address, and dangling if you forgot it had been freed already

Comment: In the upcoming C++ standard, `nullptr` will be the value of null pointers.

Comment: @Michał: in most (about all modern) architectures, `NULL==0`. But there are some architectures where it was not the case. Even worse, on these architectures `NULL!=false` so you can't even check `if(pointer)` for non-NULL there.

Comment: @SF: Not in C++.  `0` is always the null pointer, for all pointers. `0` need not correspond to the memory address 0, but the compiler will hide the details there.  So `0` is always safe to compare a pointer to.

Comment: @SF: i thought you can always check `if(pointer)` as this is interpreted as `if(pointer != 0)` and comparison of a pointer and a *constant* zero is treated as a comparison to nullptr (no matter what it is). That's for us not to worry about these architectures where the null pointer is not zero.

Comment: Always thought that there is only one category - a memory address. I'm still thinking this way. Extra classification doesn't give benefits, so it isn't needed.

Comment: @SigTerm: that fails to address NULL, which isn't a memory address or at least doesn't behave like one.

Comment: @SigTerm: While one might be able to justify ignoring the 'valid/invalid' classification, you are simply wrong about all pointers being simple memory addresses.  At the very least, the difference between a raw pointer and a pointer to member can't be ignored.

Comment: @MSalters: NULL is zero in C++. It is a macros, and doesn't have special meaning like nil in python or pascal.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Depends on what you call "member pointer". Pointer to member variable will remain normal pointer. Pointer to member function (&SomeClass::somemethod) has same size as void*, so it is still a memory address. "->" is operator. So, where is this special pointer? They are all addresses, as far as I can see.
The only special pointer I ever saw was in delphi - in one version all event handlers (technically, function pointers - TEvent, etc) were actually 8 bytes large (on 32bit) - obviously first halve stored "self"(or something similar), and second was function address.

Comment: "Pointer to member function (&SomeClass::somemethod) has same size as void*". No it doesn't, in general. Not on MSVC9 for instance.

Comment: A pointer behind a valid object is valid, but does not point to an object.

Answer (score 6):

There are also function pointers, which point to code rather than objects.  And pointers to members, which require an instance of a class to fully dereference.  And pointers to member functions, which point to code and requires and an instance of a class to fully dereference.

There are several different types of smart pointers as well.  These are used to wrap up dynamic memory allocations, and track ownership of the underlying data.  When nobody owns the data any more, the dynamic memory is automatically released.  The three biggies here are scoped pointers, shared pointers, and weak pointers.  Scoped pointers only have one owner, and when they go out of scope they get deleted [see `std::auto_ptr` in C++03 and `std::unique_ptr` in C++0x].  Shared pointers can have many owners, and the memory doesn't get freed until all the owners are done with them.  Weak pointers are a form of these, but they don't maintain strict ownership at all times; they request ownership when they need it, and that request is denied if the corresponding shared pointer has run out of owners.

Comment: Pointers to members require an *instance*, not a class to dereference.

Answer (score 5):

...adding orthogonally to Steve's answer -

- pointer to a variable (`int*`, `char*`, also **`void*`** which is a special pseudo-type which must always be cast before dereferencing. Also pointers to pointers.)
- pointer to a function (`void(*)()`, `int(*)(int)`) and so on.)

The distinction is important because one family can't be cast into the other, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You could also add another level of categorization and sort pointers according to their "constness":

**Pointer to a const** - You can change to pointer, but not what it points to.

Example:

```
int i = 42;
const int* pi = &i;
```

or

```
int i = 42;
int const* pi = &i;
```

**Const pointer** - You can't change what the pointer points to.

Example:

```
int i = 42;
int* const pi = &i;
```

**Const pointer to a const** - You can't change what the pointer points to and you can't change the pointer itself.

Example:

```
int i = 42;
const int* const pi = &i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

[C++ Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)